# Wordpress Customize not working - load-scripts.php errors

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, customization

When I try to customize my Wordpress theme, I get a blank screen. I disabled plugins and the error was still there - it's the theme, I tried a different theme and the issue was gone.

I ran the JS console and got these errors, but I don't know what they mean:

```
load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-draggable,underscore,wp-a11y,wp-util,jquery&load[]=-ui-sortable,jquery-ui-droppable,backbone,wp-backbone,jquery-ui-tabs,shortcode,utils,media-models,moxiejs,plupload,wp-plupload&ver=4.9.8:58 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at Function.m.template (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-draggable,underscore,wp-a11y,wp-util,jquery&load[]=-ui-sortable,jquery-ui-droppable,backbone,wp-backbone,jquery-ui-tabs,shortcode,utils,media-models,moxiejs,plupload,wp-plupload&ver=4.9.8:58)
    at n.template (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-draggable,underscore,wp-a11y,wp-util,jquery&load[]=-ui-sortable,jquery-ui-droppable,backbone,wp-backbone,jquery-ui-tabs,shortcode,utils,media-models,moxiejs,plupload,wp-plupload&ver=4.9.8:61)
    at n.render (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-ui-slider,jquery-touch-punch,iris,wp-color-picker,heartbeat,customize-base,customize-controls,customize-widgets,thickbox,&load[]=mce-view,imgareaselect,image-edit,quicktags,wplink,jquery-ui-position,jquery-ui-menu,jquery-ui-autocomplete,media-upload,accordi&load[]=on,customize-nav-menus,customize-models,customize-views,updates&ver=4.9.8:722)
    at n.initialize (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-ui-slider,jquery-touch-punch,iris,wp-color-picker,heartbeat,customize-base,customize-controls,customize-widgets,thickbox,&load[]=mce-view,imgareaselect,image-edit,quicktags,wplink,jquery-ui-position,jquery-ui-menu,jquery-ui-autocomplete,media-upload,accordi&load[]=on,customize-nav-menus,customize-models,customize-views,updates&ver=4.9.8:718)
    at n.e.View (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-draggable,underscore,wp-a11y,wp-util,jquery&load[]=-ui-sortable,jquery-ui-droppable,backbone,wp-backbone,jquery-ui-tabs,shortcode,utils,media-models,moxiejs,plupload,wp-plupload&ver=4.9.8:84)
    at n.constructor (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-draggable,underscore,wp-a11y,wp-util,jquery&load[]=-ui-sortable,jquery-ui-droppable,backbone,wp-backbone,jquery-ui-tabs,shortcode,utils,media-models,moxiejs,plupload,wp-plupload&ver=4.9.8:86)
    at new n (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-draggable,underscore,wp-a11y,wp-util,jquery&load[]=-ui-sortable,jquery-ui-droppable,backbone,wp-backbone,jquery-ui-tabs,shortcode,utils,media-models,moxiejs,plupload,wp-plupload&ver=4.9.8:84)
    at f.ready (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-ui-slider,jquery-touch-punch,iris,wp-color-picker,heartbeat,customize-base,customize-controls,customize-widgets,thickbox,&load[]=mce-view,imgareaselect,image-edit,quicktags,wplink,jquery-ui-position,jquery-ui-menu,jquery-ui-autocomplete,media-upload,accordi&load[]=on,customize-nav-menus,customize-models,customize-views,updates&ver=4.9.8:31)
    at Object.<anonymous> (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-ui-slider,jquery-touch-punch,iris,wp-color-picker,heartbeat,customize-base,customize-controls,customize-widgets,thickbox,&load[]=mce-view,imgareaselect,image-edit,quicktags,wplink,jquery-ui-position,jquery-ui-menu,jquery-ui-autocomplete,media-upload,accordi&load[]=on,customize-nav-menus,customize-models,customize-views,updates&ver=4.9.8:31)
    at i (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-draggable,underscore,wp-a11y,wp-util,jquery&load[]=-ui-sortable,jquery-ui-droppable,backbone,wp-backbone,jquery-ui-tabs,shortcode,utils,media-models,moxiejs,plupload,wp-plupload&ver=4.9.8:2)
```

Comment: If you know already that the issue is being caused by one theme, have you tried debugging it already? If so, what did you find?

Comment: Did someone else build this theme? If so, I would switch themes if you can.

Comment: blank screen ya say .. add this to your index.php file: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1);` just after opening php tag

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you are not the first one to have this problem. I cannot debug your problem for you (as load-scripts.php is a core file which is obvioiusly loading a lot) but *MAYBE* your problem is the same as described here: https://iansvoboda.com/code/dealing-load-scripts-php-console-errors-wordpress/

> Ultimately the issue came down to **extra white-space in the top of a functions.php include**.
>
> If your WordPress theme’s functions.php file (or any files
>   included/required inside of it) has extra white-space before the first
>   opening PHP tag, WordPress may not function correctly. The exact
>   issue(s) caused by the white-space vary depending on your setup and in
>   this case they took the form of a console error.

Therefore: Go ahead - check your theme files.